# emacs missing R syntax highlighting

Tags: r, linux, emacs, editor, text-editor

I am new to Emacs. Now I have two linux machines, old one and new one. On the old one, when I open a R file, it would show syntax highlighting like below:

[image]

But on the new machine, it does not have syntax highlighting:

[image]

I thought the settings file would be under: `~/.emacs.d/` But when I list the folder on both machine. They are exactly the same. There is only one folder called **auto-save-list**. Nothing else.

[image]

I thought I just need to copy the settings file from old machine to the new one. But now there is no settings file. Also, there is no folder for installed packages either under `~/.emacs.d/`

Can anyone tell me what the next sensible step to take to replicate emacs env to the new machine? Thank you.

Comment: You need to install *ess* https://ess.r-project.org/

Comment: settings is typically  ~/.emacs , but you need ess installed. Most should work out of the box with that.